# How to understand the problem with mustache + spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mustache

I do my first project with Spring boot and I use Mustache. So, I have a problem with it. When I try to start my application my page with database looks like this:

```
[{"dietaId":1,"nazwa":"Antycellulitowa","opis":"Na początku chcielibyśmy omówić podstawowe zasady omawianego tutaj programu żywieniowego. Przede wszystkim, dobrze jest jeść mało, lecz często. Niezwykle istotne jest także regularne przyjmowanie posiłków i nie omijanie żadnego z nich (szczególnie śniadań, które powinny dostarczać nam niezbędnej energii na resztę dnia). Dieta antycellulitowa powinna być odpowiednio zbilansowana i bogata w nieprzetworzone, świeże produkty (zwłaszcza warzywa i owoce). Najlepiej unikać jest potraw smażonych i duszonych w tłustych lub śmietanowych sosach. Zamiast tego, dobrze jest przygotowywać posiłki poprzez gotowanie na parze lub pieczenie.\r\n\r\nNiezwykle istotnym zaleceniem diety antycellulitowej jest rezygnacja lub znaczne ograniczenie soli, gdyż zatrzymuje ona w naszym organizmie wodę i toksyny. Zamiast tej przyprawy, możemy spokojnie sięgać po świeże zioła, czosnek, cebulę, bazylię, estragon, oregano itp. Nasze menu powinno składać się z chudego mięsa, drobiu, ryb oraz nabiału. Możemy także jak najczęściej sięgać po cytrusy, które wspomagają odtwarzanie wpływających na poprawę wyglądu skóry włókien kolagenu. Polecamy zapoznanie się z artykułem dotyczącym diety grapefruitowej, która jest jednym z najbardziej skutecznych programów żywieniowych wspomagających walkę ze skórką pomarańczową. Podczas walki z cellulitem świetnie sprawdzają się także działające przeciwobrzękowo produkty bogate w potas, w tym sałata, pomidory i ziemniaki. Warto sięgać również po witaminę B, którą znajdziemy w jajach, drożdżach i kiełkach zbóż. Szczególnie ważne w walce ze skórką pomarańczową są produkty zawierające kwasy tłuszczowe omega (np. oleje roślinne, ryby, orzechy, oliwa) – usprawniają one metabolizm i spalanie tkanek tłuszczowych.\r\n\r\nChcąc pozbyć się cellulitu, nie możemy zapominać o piciu co najmniej 2 litrów mineralnej wody o niskiej zawartości sodu. Wspomaga ona wydalanie z organizmu wszelkich ubocznych produktów przemiany materii, które to przyczyniają się do nasilenia efektu skórki pomarańczowej. Oprócz wody, dobrze jest pić także czerwoną i zieloną herbatę (usprawnia metabolizm) oraz napary z ziół. Zalecane są również wszystkie produkty działające moczopędnie a wiec: arbuz, pietruszka, seler, czereśnie, truskawki.\r\n\r\nPodczas stosowania diety antycellulitowej, należy unikać potraw tłustych i mocno przyprawionych (w tym popularnych w dzisiejszych czasach dań typu fast food). Zawierają one dużo soli i wysoko przetworzonych produktów, które to są odradzane w każdym odpowiednio zbilansowanym programie żywieniowym. Dobrze jest także ograniczyć słodycze i alkohol. Od czasu do czasu można oczywiście sięgnąć po lampkę czerwonego wina lub drink na bazie świeżo wyciśniętego soku, lecz lepiej unikać wysokoprocentowych trunków. Jeżeli mamy ochotę na cos słodkiego, najlepiej jest wybrać gorzką czekoladę o wysokiej zawartości kakao. Unikajmy jednak cukru w czystej postaci, mlecznych deserów a także słodzonych serków. Dobrze jest także ograniczyć lub zupełnie wyeliminować z menu czerwone mięso, tłusty ser żółty, kawę oraz wędliny. Z naszego jadłospisu należy definitywnie wykreślić słodkie napoje gazowane.\r\n\r\nJak w jednym zdaniu można scharakteryzować dietę antycellulitową? Jest to przede wszystkim zdrowy i lekki program żywieniowy. Niezwykle istotny jest też fakt, że korzyści z jego stosowania mogą być różnorodne – nie tylko znacznie zredukujemy uporczywą skórkę pomarańczową, lecz dodatkowo możemy poprawić wygląd naszej sylwetki i stan skóry. Pamiętajmy jednak, że dieta będzie skuteczna tylko i wyłącznie wtedy, jeśli nie potraktujemy jej jako metody doraźnej, lecz jako sposób odżywiania, który warto stosować przez resztę naszego życia."},
```

My controller DietaController.class:

```
@RestController
public class DietaController {
    @Autowired
    private DietaRepository dietaRepository;
    @GetMapping("/dieta")
    public List<Dieta> getAllNotes() {
        return dietaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Code of My html page Dieta.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<title>Diety</title>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
}
 body {background-color: #ffffff;}
        h1 {

            font-size:  250%;
            color:#d52440;
        }
        p {

            font-size: 150%;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Diety</h1>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Numer</th>
            <th>Nazwa</th>
            <th>Opis</th>

        </tr>

        {{#diety}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{dietaId}}</td>
            <td>{{nazwa}}</td>
            <td>{{opis}}</td>

        </tr>
        {{/diety}}

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My entity Dieta.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "diety")
public class Dieta {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="DIETA_ID") private int dietaId;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique=true, name ="DIETA_NAZWA")
    private String nazwa;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="OPIS") private String opis;
    public Dieta(){ }
    public Dieta (int dietaId,String nazwa, String opis )
    { this.dietaId = dietaId;
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.opis = opis; }
    public int getDietaId() {
        return dietaId; }
        public void setDietaId(int dietaId) {
        this.dietaId = dietaId; }
        public String getNazwa() {
        return nazwa; }
        public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa; }
        public String getOpis() {
        return opis; }
        public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis; }
}
```

What did I write wrong? Or do I have to add something?

Comment: did you add `spring-boot-starter-mustache` dependency in your project?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
...

@Controller
public class DietaController {

    @Autowired
    private DietaRepository dietaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/dieta")
    public ModelAndView getAllNotes() {


        List<Diet> diets = dietaRepository.findAll();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("diety", diets);

        return new ModelAndView("Dieta", params); // html's name
    }
}
```

You aren't actually using your mustache template, somewhere in controller you have to specified it.

The result you're getting is exactly what `dietaRepository.findAll();` returns.

Also try to find some simple Spring/Mustache examples on public git repositories or blogs, because RestController isn't supposed to return rendered templates but rather json to be reused from other services/applications.